# Data Error in WPF application output

Tags: wpf, output

In my WPF application output, I am getting this message >
Error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'TeamStandingData') from 'TeamStandingDatas' (type 'ObservableCollection`1'). BindingExpression:Path=Standing.TeamStandingDatas[2].Win; DataItem='Workspace' (HashCode=58914672); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='textBox1_Copy5'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') ArgumentOutOfRangeException:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

And I am assuming it is because I am using [2] in the WPF binding.(possibly shows when there are no values)?

I came to the conclusion because instead of using an array I tried to create an instance of each element in the array and bind it that way, and the messages were gone.

In both cases, the application works fine as expected(With or without an array)  but I prefer the collection because in my case the data is easier to manage etc.

WPF:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1_Copy5" Text="{Binding Standing.TeamStandingDatas[2].Win}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="129,264,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46"/>
```

My application compiles fine and work as expected but seeing this message means am doing something wrong or not up to a good standard?

Comment: do you have at least 3 items in collection? also consider using `ItemsControl` for collection binding

Comment: Yes!, I have 4 in my collection. when the application loads I created 4 instances. I will have a look at ItemsControl.

Comment: Thanks! that's Exactly what i needed.